# Perl DBI: Result value cut off

Tags: perl, dbi

I'm currently running into an issue where a long string fetched from the db with the select below is getting truncated. In the statement below val1 gets cut off after 115 chars when I print it out in the while loop but in the table the string is 300 chars.

Are there any Perl module configuration parameters I need to adjust?

Thanks!

```
my $sql = "SELECT val1 FROM TABLE";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql)
    or die "Can't prepare statement: $DBI::errstr";
$sth->execute() or die "Cannot execute: " . $sth->errstr();
$sth->{'LongTruncOk'} = 1;
$sth->{'LongReadLen'} = 20000;
while(my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array()) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Which DBD and what's the field's type?

Answer (score 5):

According to the [DBI documentation](https://metacpan.org/module/DBI#ATTRIBUTES-COMMON-TO-ALL-HANDLES), you must set LongReadLen (and persumably LongTruncOk) before the prepare.

> Changing the value of "LongReadLen" for a statement handle after it has been "prepare"'d will typically have no effect, so it's common to set "LongReadLen" on the $dbh before calling "prepare".